# uploading file using pure javascript for dropbox and support for xhr on firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, dropbox-api, jqxhr

I am trying to make a pure javascript app capable of uploading certain files to dropbox. However I have hit upon a roadblock . Apparently on firefox 3.6 to be able to make a cross origin POST request . Firefox first sends the Access Control headers via the option method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

However it seems that dropbox does not support the OPTIONS request for the url

http://www.dropbox.com/developers/web_docs

and thus gives a 405 error but without the auth info on my POST request i get a 403 error. Does this mean its not possible to do what I am trying to do on firefox 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does not send the necessary Access-Control-* headers necessary for CORS.

You can use jsonp to do this, but it's kind of insecure.

Comment: well jsonp also requires me run a callback which as i can see is not possible with current dropbox api ...